# Semi-additive measures for other dimensions

Tags: ssas, olap

I am looking for a way to do semi-additive aggregations on a non-time dimension.  The model I am working with is similar to a snapshot inventory warehouse.  Specifically I am analyzing processes running on a compute farm.  I have one special dimension, processes, and several other regular dimensions.  The problem is I would like to sum facts, such as memory consumption, on all the regular dimensions, but last child of each process.

If a processes was seen using 1GB of ram at one point and later seen using 2GB, saying the processes is using 3GB of ram is silly, but two processes each using a gig of ram I'd like to how that as 2GB.

Comment: It might be worth noting that SSAS does not support non-additive measures on Standard Edition.